# JavaScript setTimeout Order Of Execution

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm building a sorting algorithm visualizer, a simplified version of this https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/ComparisonSort.html . Without setTimeout functions, the array sorts itself as expected and the bars are in the correct order. But I wanted to make it animated like in that example, but after adding setTimeout functions I am getting the effect I want, but it happens out of order and sorts it wrong. I know that timeout functions are executed after the main thread but I don't understand why this is an issue, for ex. with the interval at 0 shouldn't it still sort the array correctly? To my understanding, the setTimeout Function would all run in the same order.

I tried to play around with different intervals for both setTimeOuts but even at 0 things happen out of order and the array sorts incorrectly. For context all updateSlowPointer & updateFastPointer do is highlight the jth and j + 1th bars that we are looking at. Swap, swaps two bars, just by swapping CSS classes.

```
let bubbleSort = (inputArr) => {
let len = inputArr.length;
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            updateSlowPointer(inputArr[j], inputArr[j - 1]);
            updateFastPointer(inputArr[j + 1]);
        }, 0); 

        if (inputArr[j] > inputArr[j + 1]) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                swap(inputArr[j], inputArr[j + 1]);
            }, 0);

            let tmp = inputArr[j];
            inputArr[j] = inputArr[j + 1];
            inputArr[j + 1] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
    return inputArr;
};
```

Comment: But your `if`s check *the current state*, while your mutations happen *asynchronously*

Answer (score 0):

Getting loops and asynchrony right is complicated. But we have a tool to get it right: `async` functions! You can easily `await` the loops then. Or, if you want to be able to run the algoeithms *step by step*, which I think you want, *generator functions* might be the tool of your choice:

```
  function* bubbleSort(inputArr) {
    let len = inputArr.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        updateSlowPointer(inputArr[j], inputArr[j - 1]);
        updateFastPointer(inputArr[j + 1]);
      }

      if (inputArr[j] > inputArr[j + 1]) {
        swap(inputArr[j], inputArr[j + 1]);
      }

      let tmp = inputArr[j];
      inputArr[j] = inputArr[j + 1];
      inputArr[j + 1] = tmp;

       yield inputArr; // < let other code step in here
   }
   return inputArr;
 }
```

Then you can use an `async function` to execute the generator step by step:

```
 const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

 (async function() {
     let stepper = bubbleSort([1, 3, 2]), done = false;
     while(!done) {
       ({ done, value }) = stepper.next();
       // visualization here
       console.log(value);
       await timer(1000);
     }
  })();
```